# dropdownlist dose not work in Webview when I run on service

Tags: android, service, webview

My app is floatingwindow app. I used Service to add Webview and overlay other application by WindowManager. I get a some problem when click on dropdownlist in Webview and application FC.( dropdownlist such as select language in Google Translate)

I try to test on Activity.It's working properly.
I have no idea to solve them.
Can I use service to run Webview properly like on activity?
Please guide me and sorry for my English